# Hibernate Criteria. Group functions in between section, how to do?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, criteria

I have some difficulty in creating hibernate criteria query which has "avg" function in "between" block.

part of **Shop.java**

```
@Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "shop")
public class Shop {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "shop", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Rating> ratings = new ArrayList<Rating>();
```

part of **Rating.java**

```
@Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "rating")
public class Rating {

    @Id
    private int id;

    private int value;
    private String comment;
```

Basically, l need to create SELECT query which will select from Shop such entities whose avg(ratings.value) is between, grater than or less then some numbers. I need to understand the mechanism. If you can write such query, using Hibernate Criteria API, please help me. Thank you!

**EDIT 1** The Criteria query should be from Session object not from EntityManager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Shop > cq = cb.createQuery(Shop.class);
Root<Shop > root = cq.from(Shop.class);
cq.select(root.get("id"), cb.avg(root.get("ratings")));
cq.where( cb.le(cb.avg(root.get("ratings"), 5);
cq.groupBy(c.get("id"));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I'm nit using Hibernate as persistence provider. How transform this query to Hibernate Criteria Query which l can get from Session object?